# ¿Por qué tengo este error de Foreign keys en PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

Es la primera vez que utilizo postgreSQL, versión postgreSQL 12, interfaz pgAdmin 4.
De la tabla Libros necesito crear 3 foreign keys, estas foreign keys serían las primary key(idAutor, idCategoria, idEditorial) de las tablas autores, categorias, editoriales.
Las foreign key las cree en la tabla libros de forma manual de la siguiente forma:
En Constraints (botón derecho) -> Create -> foreign key (así con cada una de las fk).
Pero las llavesitas las marca con una cruz roja como muestro a continuacion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y aca muestro la propiedad de por ejemplo la foreign key autores_idAutor_fk que pareciera estar todo bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Son primary key esas columnas en sus tablas?

Comment: No tienes especificada la coumna local que referencia la columna en la tabla foránea...

Comment: Gracias por responder, acabo de borrar todas las fk, volví a crearlas, poniendo en la columna local idAutor, sin embargo al finalizar aparece la crucesita roja, y al entrar a propiedades no me aparece nada asignado a la columna local

Comment: Creo que me falto al finalizar la fk, clic btn derecho -> validate foreign key, de esta forma la crucesita roja desapareció.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUCIONADO:

1. En Constraints **(clic botón derecho) -> Create -> foreign key -> columns** (completar los campos local column, References, referencing), clic en el botón **+** para agregar y clic en **SAVE**.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Al finalizar va a aparecer la foreign key con una crucecita roja, entonces **clic btn derecho sobre la misma -> validate foreign key**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La crucecita roja desaparece
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]